# Can I replay previous chapters without losing progress?

Tags: max-payne-3

I thought about replaying the game's first chapter to try and do better at finding some collectibles, but the game doesn't make the affect this will have on my current progress entirely clear.

I'm currently in the middle of chapter five. Will I be able to get back there if I choose to replay a previous chapter, or will I have to start (chapter five) again from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it is indeed possible to replay previous chapters without losing your current progress. After playing through a previous chapter, choosing "Continue" from the game's menu will put you right where you left off.